# copy and pasting into web input box causes strange behavior?

Tags: asp.net, html

i have a plain html form on a windows box running windows server 2003. I have come upon something very strange. I input items into an input box and click submit. It safely post to the next page. However if i copy and paste into the box its hit or miss. More miss then hit. WHat i mean is that the input box eventhough has values in it does not seem to post the values to the next aspx page. This is racking my brain.

```
<form name="sending" method="POST"  action="https://xx/Retrieveimg.aspx" target="_self"> 

    <font size="2">invoice :</font><br>
    <input name="img" size="50" runat="server">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Send">
</form>
```

has anyone ever seen this behavior before?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any jQuery or javascript add-ons?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question with your sample 'miss' values.

Comment: no javascript whatsoever... any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see you have an ID for the input which has a `runat="server"` attribute. Add an ID and try again.